# Mysql query with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

I have two tables like table A and table B. and columns names in both table A and B which are

```
        A                      B
------------------------   -----------------------  
| ID | sID | qID | fID |   | xmlText | sID | qID |
------------------------   -----------------------
| 1  |  1  |  1  | 213 |   |   xml   |  1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |  2  | 213 |   |   xml   |  1  |  2  |
| 3  |  1  |  3  | 213 |   |   xml   |  1  |  3  |
| 4  |  2  |  1  | 213 |   |   xml   |  2  |  1  |
| 5  |  2  |  2  | 213 |   |   xml   |  2  |  2  |
| 6  |  2  |  3  | 213 |   |   xml   |  2  |  3  |
| 7  |  4  |  1  | 214 |   |   xml   |  4  |  1  |
------------------------   -----------------------
```

Now i want to write a query that will select all sID and qID from table A against 213 value and pass those sID and fID to table B and get all text one by one as in below output.

```
--------------------------
| Text | sID | qID | fID |
--------------------------
| abc  |  1  |  1  | 213 |
| abc  |  1  |  2  | 213 |
| abc  |  1  |  3  | 213 |
| abc  |  2  |  1  | 213 |
| abc  |  2  |  2  | 213 |
| abc  |  2  |  3  | 213 |
--------------------------
```

I tried the below code.

```
SELECT s.territoryID, t.name, s.sectionName, s.attributeName, s.shopID, s.attributeID
FROM scoreanalysis AS s 
INNER JOIN territories AS t ON s.territoryID = t.ID 
WHERE  s.territoryID IN 
( 
  SELECT t.ID FROM territories as t 
  WHERE t.formatID = 213 and t.territorylevelID =349537 
  and t.lft > 2 and t.rht < 397
) 
AND s.achievedScore =0 AND s.applicableScore !=0
```

AND

```
SELECT questionComment from comments where 
shopID=".$row["shopID"]." and questionID=".$row["attributeID"]
```

what are possible solution to solve this problem! Any Help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: where is the text column? in which table?

Comment: paste what u tried here

Comment: text Column is in B table. @Naveen

Comment: @Gunaseelan what i tried is first i calculate the sID against 213 and kept in a array then i calculate the qIDs against count of sID array. it gives me the actual result what i want but takes a lot time(due to large data) i want to reduce the time or say optimize this in a single query instead of two.

Comment: @Gunaseelan  
SELECT s.territoryID, t.name, s.sectionName, s.attributeName, s.shopID, s.attributeID
FROM scoreanalysis AS s
INNER JOIN territories AS t ON s.territoryID = t.ID
WHERE s.territoryID 
IN ( SELECT t.ID FROM territories as t WHERE t.formatID = 213 and t.territorylevelID =349537 and t.lft > 2 and t.rht < 397) AND s.achievedScore =0 AND s.applicableScore !=0 
and i stored this result in $row array and then pass it to next query 
SELECT questionComment from comments where shopID=".$row["shopID"]." and questionID=".$row["attributeID"]

this is i tried and working fine but takes a lot ti

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly. You asked the question in MySQL and now the code is having PHP tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables together, and add the following conditions:

- sID matches
- qID matches
- tableA.fID is 213

In your select, you can pull the text, sid, and qid values from tableB, and the fid from tableA like this:

```
SELECT b.xmlText, b.sid, b.qid, a.fid
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON b.sid = a.sid AND b.qid = a.qid AND a.fid = 213;
```

Comment: This will give you duplicate answers if it isn't a 1:1 relationship

Answer (score 0):

The `exists` operator should do the trick:

```
SELECT `text`
FROM   b
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   a
               WHERE  a.sID = b.sID and a.qID = b.qID AND fID = 213)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.xmlText as Text, a.sID, a.qID, a.fID 
  FROM a, b 
  WHERE a.sID = b.sID and a.qID = b.qID AND a.fID = 213;
```

This will give you output as

```
--------------------------
| Text | sID | qID | fID |
--------------------------
| xml  |  1  |  1  | 213 |
| xml  |  1  |  2  | 213 |
| xml  |  1  |  3  | 213 |
| xml  |  2  |  1  | 213 |
| xml  |  2  |  2  | 213 |
| xml  |  2  |  3  | 213 |
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.text, a.sid, a.qid, a.fid
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.sID = b.sID AND a.qID = b.qID 
WHERE a.fID = 213;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL query:

```
SELECT `qID`,`sID`, `xmlText` AS `text` 
FROM `B` 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT `sID`, `qID`, `fID` , `id` 
    FROM `a`  
    WHERE a.sID = B.sID 
        AND a.qID=B.qID 
        AND fID=213
)
```